# how to get the values from database and get posted automatically into the dynamic textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a javacript function for adding and removing dynamic textboxes just as shown below[image]

And when i click on save values are saving into database.But my question is when i click on page(which is link) then it should display the values those are in database into these textboxes just as shown below[image]

As shown above,when i click on "Tax Info",it should automatically display the values of the database to the textboxes that are created dynamically.The code for what i had did until now is as shown below.Any idea or solution given will be appreciated.The database table is
[image]

taxInfo.jsp

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
        var values = "";
        var values1 = "";
        var values2 = "";
        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
            values += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });

        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox1]").each(function () {
            values1 += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });

        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox2]").each(function () {
            values2 += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });

        document.location.href ="taxInfoDB.jsp?values=" + values + "&values1=" + values1 + "&values2=" + values2 + "";
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });
});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' + '<input name = "DynamicTextBox1" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' + '<input name = "DynamicTextBox2" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
}
</script>

        </div>
     <div id="divMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="current" href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/Phome.jsp">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/ManageUser/Mhome.jsp">Manage User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Lead/home.jsp">Lead Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Purchase/Puhome.jsp">Purchase</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Sales/Shome.jsp">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Payroll/Phome.jsp">PayRoll</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/CustomerComplain/chome.jsp">Customer Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <div id="divLeft">
            <div id="divWelcome">
                Welcome<br /> <b>${sessionScope.name}</b>
            </div>
            <div id="divLeftTop">
                <img
                    src="/SalesPropeller/Profile/displayblob.jsp"
                    height="160" width="140" />
            </div>
            <hr />
            <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
                <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/Phome.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/profile.jsp">Admin
                        Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/addCompanyProfile.jsp">Company Profile</a></li>

                <li><a class="current" href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/taxInfo.jsp">Tax Info</a></li>
                <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu"
                    href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/message.jsp">Messages</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/compose.jsp">Compose
                                New</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/inbox.jsp">Inbox</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/Admin/Profile/outbox.jsp">Sent Messages</a></li>
                    </ul></li>
                <li><a href="/SalesPropeller/logout.jsp">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
                    var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
                    //-->
                </script>

        </div>
        <div id="divRight">
            <br />


                 <form name="form"  method="post">
            <div align="center">
                <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
<br /><br/>
<b style="padding-right:100px">Name of the Tax</b> <b style="padding-right:100px">Value</b> <b style="padding-right:100px">TaxGroup</b>  
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
    <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
</div>
<br />
<input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Save" />
</div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

taxInfoDB.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.model.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.DecimalFormat"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tax Saving Database</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
String values = request.getParameter("values");
String values1 = request.getParameter("values1");
String values2 = request.getParameter("values2");
System.out.println("values are:"+values);
System.out.println("values1 are:" +values1);
System.out.println("values2 are:" +values2);
try{
    DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
    Connection con = db.getCon();
    String sql ="insert IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON into marketing_database.tax_info (TaxGroup,Name,Value) values (?,?,?);";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, values2);
    ps.setString(2, values);
    ps.setString(3, values1);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    con.close();
    ps.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
        }

response.sendRedirect("taxInfo.jsp");
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the issue in the code? And where is the code for fetching the table value(s)?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan I dont have any idea on how to do it.So i posted for what i had done until now.Do you have any idea??

Comment: In `taxinfo.jsp` write code for fetch data and from resultset iterate it and populate in text boxes.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan Populating in the textboxes?? its like a normal one i knew it.But i need like when i click on "TaxInfo" which is present in left side of the boxes in the above image it should automatically click the "Add" button and how many values are there in database those many textboxes it should create(automatically) and those values are placed in  the textboxes(these process should be in fraction of seconds when i click on "TaxInfo" tag page).

Comment: I understood that, when you are iterating you can create the text boxes too. Place three textboxes inside of loop. Values should be coming from dB. Then it will populate automatically

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try MVC model.
Simply speaking, you might want to put all your Java code in a .java file. In that java class, you could read data from Database into java object and put that object in HttpServletRequest, HttpSession or application and sendRedirect to the jsp page. In jsp page you could then read data from the previously set object.